# Response for first query to AWS Elasticsearch is very slow from lambda function written in java using JestClient

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, jest-client

While querying AWS Elasticsearch from lambda function written in java, first call takes around 25 seconds and subsequent calls (same query) take less than a second.
This happens if i don't query Elasticsearch for quite some time like say 5 minutes.

Comment: Is this a Java Lambda cold-start issue?

Comment: You need to add some timing logging.  The Lambdas that I have in Java have a cold start of less than a second.  Some code might help too.

Comment: Yes, after adding timing logs only I got to know about it.
if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(model.getAutoType(), "PLACE")) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 //Elastic Search Call Using JestClient
    List<AgentESSModel> withAds = AgentSearchHepler.searchESS(model.getSearchString(), true);
    LOGGER.debug("Time taken " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
}

Comment: I've added timing logs at the start  and end of the method. Anyways, you are right about the cold start time, it is less than a second for  functions written in java.

Comment: Finally, I figured out the problem. JestClient wasn't causing any problem at all, it was just the way I had initialized it. Too many unnecessary DynamoDB calls where happening and were slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Cold start will not cause 25 seconds delay. 
My hunch is that your elastic search query must be inappropriate and taking time to get result. After first call it gets cached automatically at elastic search end and you get faster result. Please verify this statement by making the query directly via postman and additionally passing request_cache=false in querystring
Alternate way is to test with a simple elasticsearch query

To avoid cold start you can set provisioned capacity for your lambda function

Comment: My query is combination of must, prefix and must not clauses.
 
 Verified, from Postman, it takes same time.
 
 So, If I set request_cache = false, it is going to take same time always?
 
 Beisdes, I'm trying to pull 1K records, is that a problem?

Comment: One more thing I noticed, If I run same query from another function written in Node js, it takes maximum of 1.5 seconds always. I think the JestClient I'm using in lambda function written in java, is slow.

Comment: @AsraarWani : request_cache=false i suggest only to verify the test. Yes, as i mentioned, it will take similar time with caching false.
Trying to pull 1K records is not problem, from how many shards they are fetched and query complexity makes the difference.
-- Please mark the ans if it was helpful